# Error when installing the Sceneform plugin and using alternatives with .glb and .gltf files

Tags: android, 3d, arcore, gltf, sceneform

I want to make use of the Sceneform example using my own models but when installing the plugin it gives an error, the msn shows that: *"Plugin error:" Google Sceneform Tools (Beta) "plugin is not supported (only supported in IntelliJ IDEA)"* . I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 and the plugin version is 1.15.0.

I have downloaded Android studio 3.4, but after the plugin installation Android Studio does not start, it shows a msn: *"Android Studio stopped working. The program stopped working correctly due to a problem ...".*

I know that this plugin is obsolete and that this version includes the option of being able to use .glb and .gltf files. The point is that I have replaced the .sfb file with a .glb and .gltf and it doesn't work at all. I have tried updating the plugin libraries within my gradle to 1.11.0 and 1.15.0 with no result. **The question is, is there a way to use this either with .sft or .glb and .gltf files?**